# Fail to start dhcpcd@eth0.service

Tags: networking

I'm running latest Raspbian Stretch Lite (Released @ 2018-06-27) on 3B+ for a project. For network interface dhcp part, I want to enable & start dhcpcd on some specific interfaces instead of starting it on all. But when I run the following cmd in the shell, I got some error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~# sudo systemctl start dhcpcd@eth0.service
Failed to start dhcpcd@eth0.service: Unit dhcpcd@eth0.service not found.
```

I got the instruction on running this cmd from dhcpcd wiki page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd#dhcpcd_and_systemd_network_interfaces.

The system is fresh burned to the SD card.

I can manually bring up all the interface (eth0, wlan0) with dhcpcd  cmd and can also bring up them if I enable dhcpcd.service globally.

Appreciated if someone can help me on this.

Cheers,
Wayne

Comment: so, you're using `archlinux` documentation in `raspbian` and wondering why it doesn't work? what interfaces does your system have?

Comment: Of course, what you want to achieve is possible by simply editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` with appropriate information

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes. But it seems there is no unit files for separate interface on raspbian. Not sure if there is such files on arch because I don't have arch now. I do have eth0, wlan0 interfaces in the system which I can see in ip link show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is "*Fail to start dhcpcd@eth0.service. Why?*"

For interface specific unit files you must have a unit ending with `@` before *.device* as you can see with, for example:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl list-unit-files *wpa*
UNIT FILE               STATE
wpa_supplicant.service  disabled
wpa_supplicant@.service indirect
```

dhcpcd has no such unit file. Verify with

```
rpi ~$ systemctl list-unit-files *dhcp*
UNIT FILE       STATE
dhcpcd.service  enabled
dhcpcd5.service enabled
```

So your command `sudo systemctl start dhcpcd@eth0.service` cannot work.

What you want to achieve is to setup DHCP only on specific devices. It seems you like to do it with *systemd*. It can easily be done with *systemd-networkd*. Because you haven't given any information about your network configuration I cannot give you specific advices. But here is an example with **eth0** with a static ip address and **wlan0** with getting its ip address by DHCP.

### Step 1: Switch over to systemd-networkd

Just follow to [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). You can use section **"♦ Quick Step"**. Then come back here.

### Step 2: Configure interfaces

Create these files for interfaces **eth0** and **wlan0** with your settings:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Address=192.168.0.2/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
DHCP=yes
EOF
```

Reboot.

For additional interfaces create a new `/etc/systemd/network/<nn-if>.network` file with its specific settings. Look at `man systemd.network`.

Comment: Yes. There is no dhcpcd unit files for separate interfaces in Raspbian Stretch which is the cause of this failure. In my scenario, I want to have two modes of network setup. One is automatic dhcp on all interfaces which is OK if I make some configuration in dhcpcd.conf. Another one is manually dhcp on specific interfaces which means I would disable dhcpcd.service and start dhcpcd@interface.service manually without touching dhcpcd.conf. I don't think I can do this by dhcpcd.conf. Maybe I should try to add some unit files.

Comment: @WayneWu I have updated my answer.

Comment: This didn't do the task for me.

Comment: @Enku What's the problem?

Comment: @Ingo I wasn't able to create the network by switching to systemd-networkd. So, I had to backup and reformat the memory card and not it's working by the default dhcpcd service.

Comment: @Enku I have updated Step 1 of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> "I want to enable & start dhcpcd on some specific interfaces instead of starting it on all"

---

For such Usage would the config with `/etc/network/interfaces` fit more.

1. First deactivate the interface for example `ifdown eth0`
2. Open the Config file `nano /etc/network/interfaces`
3. For example activate dhcp on eth0, add the followling line 
   `auto eth0` 
   `iface eth0 inet dhcp`
4. Safe the file
5. Bring up eth0 again `ifup eth0`

Comment: good answer for Raspbian wheezy - not so much for Jessie and Stretch

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question whether you wish to disable permanently or change from time to time.

**Advanced dhcpcd Configuration** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) discusses the more common settings which can be customised.

There is only ONE service file - if you need to change run `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd`