# Run commands on boot of raspberry pi

Tags: boot

I am attempting to use my pi to share an internet connection on wifi with the ethernet port.  I am able to get it to work by running these commands in terminal:

```
sudo service dhcpcd restart
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT
sudo service dnsmasq start
```

That part I have figured out.  What I have not figured out is how to run these commands on restart of the pi.  I have tried putting them in the rc.local file as some online suggestions but does not work on boot up.  These commands do run on starting a new terminal server session.

I have tried the ideas on this page, https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/ and https://raspberrytips.com/autostart-a-program-on-boot/ but have not been successful.  Some suggestion refer to running a program or a script file or a service.  I do not know how to take these commands and turn them into a script file, program or service.

I know the code does what I want it to.  You help to get it running on boot up would be a big help.  thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this. One way is to put "it" in `rc.local`, but that's hardly ever the best way to do it. Using `systemd` is the *new* way, and perhaps the *best* way to do it, but not the simplest way. Using `cron` is a third way, and that is what we shall try here.

Be forewarned: I usually try these things on my Pi before I put them in an answer, but I'm not going to do that in this case. Consequently, there may be a bit of "trial-and-error" to get this working. That said, here we go:

As always, you should be armed with *some* background before you begin copying and pasting, so please read, or briefly peruse, the following *system manuals*:

```
$ man cron       # the daemon/service that makes all of this possible
$ man crontab    # your instructions to cron
$ man 5 crontab  # details on how to write crontab
```

If you've not used system manuals before, you type the letter `q` to exit a man page & return to the CLI.

The version of `cron` used in Raspbian provides a feature that allows us to start a program when the system boots. Here's how to use that:

```
$ crontab -e      # "e" = edit; if prompted to select an editor - choose nano
```

You are now in the `nano` editor. At the bottom of the file, add the following:

```
@reboot /bin/echo "System rebooted at: $(date)" >> /home/pi/mydatalog.txt 2>&1
```

In `nano`, save the file, exit `nano` & reboot your system. Afterwards, login again & find the file `mydatalog.txt` in your (user pi I've assumed) home directory. Open it in `nano` & verify the time you re-booted. If all this worked, you've just created a *cron job* that logs each system reboot to a file. If you're happy with this, leave it; if not use `crontab -e` to change it, or delete the line entirely if you like.

In your question, you ask about running commands that require `root` privileges to run. In this case, I feel it's best to use *root's crontab* instead of your own, but for Raspbian, this may not be necessary. Since this is my answer, we'll do it this way:

```
$ sudo crontab -e      # opens root's crontab for editing
```

Note that *root's crontab* is a different `crontab` as you will not see the line you added in the steps above. Enter the following in `nano`:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 30; /usr/sbin/service dhcpcd restart && /bin/sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" && /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE && /usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT && /usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT && /usr/sbin/service dnsmasq start >> /home/pi/netsharelog.txt 2>&1
```

Save this file in `nano` & exit. Now reboot your system. Let us know if you have any issues or questions.

Answer (score 3):

As you already noted, running commands at bootup is done with a service on a modern operating system using **systemd**. Together with its built-in networking `systemd-networkd` it is very easy to setup routing with network address translation (NAT), as you want.

How to setup this you can look at [How to make Raspberry Pi 4 as “WIFI” -> “Ethernet” adaptor](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/112428/79866). Just replace **wlan0** everywhere given in the example with **wlan1** for your interface.

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  It appears these are directions for making the pi wifi access point which is not what I am trying to do.  I am using the internet connection that is on wlan1 and sharing it to the ethernet port so I can connect via ethernet cable to a switch and any computer connected to that switch can get internet access via the pi's wifi connection.  If you can point me to how to take these commands and turn them into a service and launch it at boot that would be helpful.

Comment: @Andrew Ah, that way around, misunderstood it. No problem. I have changed the answer to link to the correct tutorial.

Comment: Link to a link to a link  :)  I'll vote for this one, too!

Comment: @Seamus Thanks; always the same questions, same questions, same questions :-) I try to reduce redundant information to have an easy update on important settings. I would prefer to close the question as duplicate, but there is nearly no chance to get 5 votes in short time.