# How can I have the raspberry pi run scripts portably?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, remote, script, input-device

I am a noobie and just got a raspberry pi yesterday and I want to create a wifi strength device with my raspberry pi. I have a wireless adapter and alreaady made a script for my linux machine. It basically just prints out the wifi strength of the current connection. Now what I want to do is put this script onto the pi, connect it to a portable battery and walk around my house testing the wifi strength and just have it's output piped with a reverse shell. I got all the script stuff taken care of my only problem is how can I run have this script running on the pi portably?

So far what I can do is connect all the computer accessories to the pi then manually execute the script with the keyboard but obviously I cant walk around my house with a keyboard, mouse, monitor ....

On the arduino you can flash instructions to the arduino and it will run when disconnected to the host computer as long as its connected to a battery supply. Is there anyway I can do something similar with the raspberry pi?

Raspberry pi model 4b 2gb ram

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run commands on boot of raspberry pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112554/run-commands-on-boot-of-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Ah I see thats a clever way to do it. Yes it does thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the Arduino.

I would suggest installing and implementing Node-Red to make your life easy.

Your Raspberry Pi has built in Wifi.

With Node-Red you can install a "node" that scans wifi, and will output a payload. You can then wire this payload to a file write "node" to dump the data into a file location on the Pi SD.

There are 101 ways to implement this and improve upon what you are doing.

You could even go as far as hosting an http endpoint from the pi to display this data,  and say with a "web button" to click and trigger the "Wifi" sampling.

You can even wire a push button to the Pi GPIO, and even have an "input" box in the http endpoint (webpage) so you can input "Kitchen" "Room 1" "Room 2"  etc. and attach that data to the msg payload, and then dump to a file.

You can even send that data remotely if you maintain connection to the internet.

But for your case, I would map out a interval timer, say 20 sec intervals, that triggers the Wifi sample, and set a map course of your sample area of your home, and every 20 seconds move to the next waypoint.  Then this timer will sample the wifi signal and then send that payload to the file.

I think there are phone apps that do this.  So you might be over killing with the Raspberry Pi.