# When my Raspberry PI 4 boots to Desktop, how do I make it automatically open the terminal, and run a command?

Tags: pygame

I've got a pygame script that I'd like to run automatically when I turn on my raspberry pi 4.

The pygame script has a GUI so it's important that the script runs in a terminal on the Desktop and I'm able to see it through something like VNC Viewer.

On raspberry pi 4 64 bit os.

Comment: your question has been asked, and answered, many times here

Comment: You don't run a GUI script in a terminal. If you want help ask a concrete question and explain what you actually want to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run commands on boot of raspberry pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112554/run-commands-on-boot-of-raspberry-pi)