# Use Pi 4 to bridge wifi to ethernet router

Tags: raspbian, networking, hotspot

I have my pc connected to the iPhone hotspot. My router is connected to the pc using Connectify. I have multiple devices connected to the router. What I would like to do is replace the pc with the Raspberry. Is there an easy way to connect the router to the Raspberry while the Raspberry is connected to the iPhone data? I don’t know what term to use for the function I would be using.  Maybe an access point, bridge, or host.

Comment: Welcome.  It's not clear what you want to do.  Do you want to connect the iphone to a hotspot running on the Pi, or vice versa?  What is the relevance of the router?

Comment: Why do you need to use the Raspberry as a bridge?  The router doesn't have wifi?

Comment: Also: *"**Instead of** connecting multiple devices to iPhone"* implies you don't want to use the iphone hotspot at all, you want the Pi to act as one (ie., as an access point to the router).  That means the iphone really doesn't have anything much to do with this -- it is just one more device you want to connect.  If you do not explain yourself in better detail, you are unlikely to get any help.

Comment: What device connect to the internet? The router or the iPhone? If the iPhone connect to the internet, for what do you need the router?

Comment: What's a bit confusing: a WiFi hotspot does not connect to anything. It is established and other devices can connect to it, like your pc. But why do you establish a WiFi hotspot with your iPhone? Do you want to use the internet connection of the iPhone for the pc, so that you can connect to the internet on your pc when connected to the hotspot? Why do you need the router? For what is it? How do you connect to it? Does the router also establish a WiFi access point (hotspot), or do you connect wired to it?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear how the PC is connected to the router. I assume it is connected wired with an ethernet cable. I also assume you want to use the iPhones internet connection to give all devices on your local network access to the internet. With this conditions you have to use the Raspberry Pi as additional router, instead of the PC. Its wired port (interface **eth0**) is connected to the already available router and with its WiFi device (interface **wlan0**) it is connected to the iPhones hotspot using a WiFi client connection. Now the RasPi must be configured to route the network traffic between the two interfaces **eth0** and **wlan0**.

You can look [how to use a Raspberry Pi as WiFi router](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/112428/79866). In this example just replace the words **"desktop computer"** (not confusing it with your PC) with your router and **"WiFi internet router"** (not confusing it with your already available router) with your iPhone. Then it should do.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes the pc is connected to the router with a Ethernet cable.