# I need my Raspberry Pi 4 to assign a local static IP to Ethernet connected client

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-4, ethernet

I need to establish a TCP/IP and/or UDP connection between Raspberry Pi and a special sensor which is not very configurable, but it has Ethernet.
Normally, this sensor is connected to a PC or PC-like device (through Ethernet, directly) which runs a special software.
Neither Raspberry Pi nor the sensor have access to the internet.

So, in order to get them to communicate I need Raspberry Pi to assign a local IP to this sensor.
I tried to set up a DHCP server with no luck, service fails to start. This is my configuration:

Answer (score 2):

You can use **systemd-networkd** to simply configure the wired ethernet interface. Please follow to [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). You can just use section **♦ Quick Step** there and then come back here. To configure the **eth0** interface, create this file:

```
rpi ~$ cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-wired.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=e*
[Network]
Address=192.168.50.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
EOF
```

Connect the sensor and reboot.

Comment: I found a simpler way actually, but I will also try your recommendation, thank you!

Comment: @BrainTrance It would be nice if you make an answer about your solution to share it with the community. I'm also interested in a simpler solution.