# How to set up wifi station mode and access point mode simultaneously and keep ZeroConf

Tags: wifi, access-point, hotspot

I have a raspberry pi zero with raspbian buster OS.
I followed [this tutorial to set up station mode and access point mode simultaneously](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge/89804#89804), and it works.

Question is now I cannot visit my rpi zero with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` , I'll have to type in it's IP address like `ssh pi@192.168.1.101`.

In the above link, at the "first step" it mentioned [another link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking/108593#108593) that removes avahi-daemon, I think that's why bonjour-zeroconf feature is disabled, because it needs avahi-daemon.

So How can I have wifi station mode and access point and also keep zeroconf, so that I can visit my rpi with `XXX.local`?

Comment: You are right. I didn't have a focus on zeroconf and I have to revise it. There are settings available in the `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` files like `LinkLocalAddressing=yes|no` and `MulticastDNS=yes|no`. There may also be related information at `man systemd.dnssd`. I will look at it next because I'm just busy with another project. Please be patient a bit.

Answer (score 2):

We use **systemd-networkd** which has its own multicast DNS system. That is the reason why we deinstall the `avahi-daemon` to avoid conflicts.

It is simple to enable multicast DNS with adding an option to the `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` configuration files. I have revised the setup for an [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) that you used. Have a look at the `*.network` configuration files. On some you will find additional options:

```
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
```

Add these also to your setup and you should find `raspberrypi.local` again. Check with:

```
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi.local
raspberrypi.local: 192.168.50.26               -- link: wlan0

-- Information acquired via protocol mDNS/IPv4 in 269.0ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```