# Working with multiple linux network interfaces

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireless, sockets

I'm running an application, where I need to use the LAN interface as a communication input with a device, using a socket server open on the IP for that interface, make the handling of this data and then send it to another server through the wireless interface. Searching a little, I tried to use the metrics configuration of the interfaces, inside the `/etc/network/interfaces` file as follows:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.20.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        metric 200

iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.154
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.10.1
        metric 100
```

However, when the LAN interface is connected to the device, traffic is interrupted on the wireless interface and using the `route -n` command I realize that the metrics made no difference, where eth0 is with metric 202 and wireless interface with metric 303.

I performed these tests using a Raspberry PI4 as Ubuntu LTS Server 20:04:01 Arm64 and also the Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop, both had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used **Ubuntu** so far, so I cannot say anything about it. But with the **Raspberry Pi OS**, you also used, you should not use `/etc/network/interfaces` anymore, because it is deprecated on RaspiOS as noted in the interfaces file. It seems you only want to configure a simple router. I prefer to use  **systemd-networkd**. You will find some examples to [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). Just follow the sections **♦ Create interface file for a wired connection** and **♦ Create interface file for a WiFi connection**.

There you will not find additional options like **ip-forward** and **NAT** for a complete router. I cannot see from the question that you need it. If you need additional options just tell me.