# Cannot access RPi server (node js) from a browser using hostname

Tags: networking, ssh, windows, node.js, dns

I set hostname of my Raspberry Pi 3 to "myhost", avahi is running ok (systemctl confirmed, to run with myhost.local).

From my Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10 I can ssh to the RPi with `ssh pi@myhost` and that works, but `ssh pi@myhost.local` does not. Similarly, from Windows cmd, `nslookup myhost` gives correct IP, but `nslookup myhost.local` says `Non-existent domain`. Why? Every tutorial on the net says to ssh with ".local".

In any case, I started a simple web server in node.js:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '192.168.1.25';   
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) =>   {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () =>    {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

And when I open Firefox and type `http://192.168.1.25:3000/` - it works, I see "Hello World". But if I type `http://myhost:3000` or `http://myhost.local:3000/` - it doesn't work (no server found).

However, from Ubuntu console on the same Windows, both `wget 192.168.1.25:3000` and `wget http://myhost:3000` - work.

**Windows resolves the domain correctly, i.e. `nslookup myhost` gives the correct IP, so why Firefox (or Chrome) cannot connect??**

Comment: Are you using apache or apache2 with this?

Comment: This is a Windows problem.

Comment: I'm not using apache at all. For server just Node JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly three services used for name resolution in a network, in particular together with MS Window$:

1. [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) (Domain Name Service) the main name service all over the world, supported by any internet provider. It resolve hierarchical organized names like `raspberrypi.stackexchange.com`.
2. [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) (multicast DNS) an auto configuring name resolution service, but only usable on **one** local network with same ip address range (broadcast domain). **mDNS** cannot pass router. It resolve names within the reserved DNS domain `.local`, e.g. `raspberrypi.local`.
3. [LLMNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) (Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution) a service made by Microsoft and supported by *Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10* and *systemd-networkd*. It is also only usable on a broadcast domain. It resolve the simple hostname, e.g. `raspberrypi`.

It is difficult to examine with your description what services in what combination is running on what device. But to shine a light on this, I have made some tests so you may be able to understand how your name resolution (should) work(s).

I have a Laptop as testing device, [configured with **systemd-networkd**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866), because that supports all services. The tested Raspberry Pi 4B is setup with the default [Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite 2020-08-20](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2020-08-24/), updated with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo reboot` at 2020-09-26. Both are connected wired to my local network with router and switches.

### Test for DNS

Setting on the Laptop. You get only an address resolution for `google.com`, not for `raspberrypi.local` and `raspberrypi`.

```
laptop ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-wired.network
[Match]
Name=ens1

[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=no
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
UseDNS=yes

laptop ~$ resolvectl status ens1
Link 2 (ens1)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 84.200.69.80
         DNS Servers: 84.200.69.80
                      84.200.70.40

laptop ~$ resolvectl query google.com
google.com: 216.58.206.14                      -- link: ens1
            2a00:1450:4001:81f::200e           -- link: ens1

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 10.4583s.
-- Data is authenticated: no
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi.local
raspberrypi.local: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi
raspberrypi: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
```

### Test for mDNS

Setting on the Laptop. You only get an address resolution for `raspberrypi.local`, not for `google.com` and `raspberrypi`.

```
laptop ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-wired.network
[Match]
Name=ens1

[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
UseDNS=no

laptop ~$ resolvectl status ens1
Link 2 (ens1)
      Current Scopes: mDNS/IPv4
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

laptop ~$ resolvectl query google.com
google.com: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi.local
raspberrypi.local: 192.168.50.60               -- link: ens1

-- Information acquired via protocol mDNS/IPv4 in 59.9ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi
raspberrypi: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
```

### Test for LLMNR

Setting on the Laptop. You do not get any address resolution if using the default *Raspberry Pi OS* image. You get a response for `raspberrypi` if configured for LLMNR.

```
laptop ~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/04-wired.network
[Match]
Name=ens1

[Network]
LLMNR=yes
MulticastDNS=no
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
UseDNS=no

laptop ~$ resolvectl status ens1
Link 2 (ens1)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

laptop ~$ resolvectl query google.com
google.com: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi.local
raspberrypi.local: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi
raspberrypi: resolve call failed: 'raspberrypi' not found
```

As expected, the default Raspberry Pi OS image does not support **LLMNR** out of the box. I don't know why your RasPi is responding to a single `myhost`. Do you use a default Raspberry Pi OS on it? To verify it, I have reconfigured my RasPi to **systemd-networkd** and enabled **LLMNR** on it. The Result is:

```
laptop ~$ resolvectl query raspberrypi
raspberrypi: 192.168.50.60                     -- link: ens1

-- Information acquired via protocol LLMNR/IPv4 in 110.0ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

Of course you can combine all services but it doesn't make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Thanks for interesting answer. I spend so much time debugging now, but to no avail. I've changed host name and now even nslookup doesn't show. Also, I cannot SSH now from my WSL with "ssh pi@myhostmy" (or .local) - the new domain. It doesn't resolve. I set the static IP so I can access my RPi. Avahi seems to be happy with itself - says it's working and serving myhostmy.local - but it doesn't work... Even when I execute `host myhostmy` or `host myhostmy.local` on the RPi itself it cannot find IP. It doesn't even see itself. I got really tired, I guess I have to be happy with static IP.

Comment: Also, I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that I'm using WiFi on RPi. Although I connected a cable - and it didn't change anything. And `nslookup myhost` on Win and `host myhost` on Linux still shows correct IPs (for wlan0 and eth0) - even though this host (myhost) doesn't exist anymore (it's myhostmy now). I tried flushing DNS but it still shows old one, while it cannot find a new one.

Comment: @zupazt3 You only focus on **DNS** but not on **mDNS** and **LLMNR**. `nslookup` and `host` only query DNS. You should use `resolvectl`. I suggest to troubleshoot structured. Flash a SD Card with an unmodified RaspiOS Lite and boot the RasPi with it. Then use a another device (Laptop, PC, second RasPi) and [configure it with systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). Then repeat the tests I have shown. Now you know what is working on the RasPi. Next try to connect from your other devices. Then you know what they support.

Comment: Seems like a logical solution. I will try this when I have some time to get back to this. Right now I guess I'd be happy with static IP and assigning it to a name using "host" file in Windows.