# Dual Access Point Connection Issue

Tags: networking, access-point, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I'm trying to setup two wireless AP on a Raspberry Pi. Lets call the two APs `AP0` and `AP1`.
I use `hostapd` to setup the APs and `dnsmasq` as the dhcp server.

`AP0` is setup on the built-in WiFi on the RasPi at `wlan0`

`AP1` is setup on an external USB adapter that supports AP mode at `wlan1`

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.43.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

 auto wlan1
 allow-hotplug wlan1
 iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.4.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd1.conf
```

and this is my `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file:

```
dhcp-range=wlan0,192.168.43.50,192.168.43.150,24h

dhcp-range=wlan1,192.168.4.50,192.168.4.150,24h
```

`AP0` and `AP1` are on channels 6 and 11 respectively.

I am able to connect multiple clients to `AP1` and the clients can speak to each other.
But the issue is with `AP0` where the client connects for a second and then disconnects and this keeps on repeating. How to fix this issue?

Comment: I never used deprecated `/etc/network/interfaces' since years. Are you open to use a solution with **systemd-networkd**?

Comment: Sure. I didn't know that `/etc/network/interfaces` is deprecated :)

Comment: It depends on the operating system you are using. I supposed that you use a Raspberry Pi OS based on buster. That is using `dhcpcd` with a hint in `/etc/network/interfaces`. What operating system do you use?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Raspberry Pi OS based on buster. Does that mean I don't require a seperate dhcp server like `dnsmasq`?

Comment: Yes, with `systemd-networkd` you do not need additional helpers like `dnsmasq` and `hostapd`. Just a moment please I'm just testing the double access point setup and will give you then an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment you are also agreed with using **systemd-networkd**. Here in short a configuration I have just tested, based on [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).

#### Switch over to systemd-networkd

Just follow to [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). You can use section **"♦ Quick Step"**. Then come back here.

#### Configure wpa_supplicant as access points

To configure *wpa_supplicant* as access point create these two files with your settings for `country=`, `ssid=`, `psk=` and maybe `frequency=`. You can just copy and paste this in one block to your command line beginning with `cat` and including both EOF (delimiter EOF will not get part of the file):

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="AP0"
    mode=2            # access point
    frequency=2437    # channel 6
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN WPA
    psk="password"
}
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="AP1"
    mode=2            # access point
    frequency=2462    # channel 11
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN WPA
    psk="password"
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
rpi ~# rfkill unblock wlan
```

#### Configure network interfaces

Create the following two files to configure the interfaces:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=192.168.43.1/24
MulticastDNS=yes
DHCPServer=yes
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-wlan1.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan1
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
MulticastDNS=yes
DHCPServer=yes
EOF
```

Reboot and it should do.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm trying it out now. I noticed the network configuration files start with a different number. Any reason for that?

Comment: @mottom The network configuration files are executed in alphabetical order so you can control it. It is good practice to prefix them with a number as already done with old style SysV init scripts. In this case it doesn't matter which access point is first started.

Comment: This is what I did. I disabled `dnsmasq.service` and `hostapd.service`, replaced the `interfaces` and `dnsmasq.conf` files with their originals (as they would be in a fresh install) and followed the steps as per the solution. I tried to connect clients to `AP0` and `AP1` but the client isn't assigned an IP address so it doesn't connect to either AP. Anything I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: @mottom Start with a fresh flashed [raspios_lite_armhf-2020-08-24](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2020-08-24/) to a spare SD Card on a Raspberry Pi 4B. Don't forget Quick steps on [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866).

Comment: Thanks @Ingo, the solution works as expected. However I don't seem to have access to WAN anymore. I use a wireless USB modem/stick connected to the Pi.

Comment: Ah, there is a third interface? You didn't told that. If the driver of the modem is working and you get an interface name then it shouldn't be a big issue to create an additional `.network` file for it. The best would be if you create a new question about it.