# DNS problems Raspbian despite seemingly correct DNS settings

Tags: raspbian, networking, internet, dns, ping

I suddenly couldn't wget a file after having gotten one 5 mins before.

I can no longer "ping google.com"

I can "ping 1.1.1.1"

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
#Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

`ifconfig` for eth0(which is what I am using):

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.142  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::15b5:7a2e:8121:e45e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:43:a3:9b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 11804  bytes 1565414 (1.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2577  bytes 301865 (294.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output from `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
 0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
 10.6.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
 192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Result from `traceroute 1.1.1.1`

```
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.420 ms  0.398 ms  0.369 ms
2  10.200.211.1 (10.200.211.1)  2.708 ms  2.540 ms  2.494 ms
3  192.38.10.89 (192.38.10.89)  21.809 ms  21.779 ms  21.640 ms
4  130.225.245.13 (130.225.245.13)  8.338 ms  8.277 ms  11.434 ms
5  109.105.102.160 (109.105.102.160)  9.342 ms  9.145 ms  9.119 ms
6  109.105.97.117 (109.105.97.117)  8.959 ms  9.468 ms  9.970 ms
7  212.237.193.246 (212.237.193.246)  10.997 ms 212.237.192.246 (212.237.192.246)  11.016 ms 10.305 ms
8  1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1)  10.643 ms  10.550 ms  9.560 ms
```

Comment: Sounds as an intermittent error?

Comment: @MatsK Doubt it, all other devices on the network works fine and I am consistentently getting this problem on my PI, haven't had it working once since the first error

Comment: Your question appears to have nothing to do with Raspberry Pi, per se, but with your network configuration. *Why* have you set `1.1.1.1` as your primary DNS? It looks like an odd choice.

Comment: @Seamus Maybe not per se, but if I need to change some configuration file I don't know I would need a pointer. `1.1.1.1` is faster than `8.8.8.8`. I have also tested it with 8.8.8.8 as primary dns

Comment: Ah! I see now that `1.1.1.1` is the "cloudFare" DNS. Turning to your `route -n` output, what is `wg0`? 2nd Q: Have you made any changes to your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file

Comment: @Seamus Yeah, cloudflare.... i totally knew it was cloudflare and not a new company by it self.  About wg0... i actually don't know. A quick search online says it's wireguard vpn(a virtual apdapter i assume). I don't know if wireguard is installed. I will report back in a bit

Comment: @Seamus Wireguard uninstalled and the output of 'route -n':
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

Comment: OK - it's always good troubleshooting to eliminate variables. You may want to edit your question to reflect this new information. Other than that - have you made any changes to your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file?

Comment: I have, a bit. I can't post it here though, should I try commenting everything out so it is effectively empty? Or rename it temporarily?

Comment: @ThomasNykjær: Two things: **1)** Comments to others under a question (or answer) **you** have authored must mention the user handle (`@whatever`) for them to get a notification.   **2)** You should *consider* using `systemd-networkd` instead of `dhcpcd` to control your network config - due to your non-standard setup. [A good how-to is here.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking/108593#108593)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was at least partially due to a wrong configuration file.
The file: /etc/nsswitch.conf
mdns4 needed to be changed to dns