# How to disable the dynamic IP address after assigning a static IP in Bullseye?

Tags: pi-3, static-ip, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, dynamic-ip

## Background

I upgraded my Pi3B from Buster to Bullseye using [these instructions](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323279).

WiFi is disabled on the Pi. Before the upgrade I had static IP setup and working fine by adding the following lines to the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
# Custom static IP address for eth0
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.65/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

After upgrade to Bullseye the static IP address stopped working and a dynamic IP address 192.168.0.146 was assigned to the Pi. I found out that the Ethernet Interface name has changed from `eth0` to `enxb827ebaceb8a`. So, I edited `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to:

```
# Custom static IP address for enxb827ebaceb8a
interface enxb827ebaceb8a
...
...
...
```

Now I have two IP addresses assigned to the same interface `enxb827ebaceb8a`. The `hostname -I` give `192.168.0.65 and 192.168.0.146`. `ifconfig` shows:

```
enxb827ebaceb8a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.65  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::10aa:7b63:4089:8d73  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:ac:eb:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 74307  bytes 7398372 (7.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 72692  bytes 23849203 (22.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`sudo dhclient -v` shows:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Listening on LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:f9:be:df
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:f9:be:df
Listening on LPF/enxb827ebaceb8a/b8:27:eb:ac:eb:8a
Sending on   LPF/enxb827ebaceb8a/b8:27:eb:ac:eb:8a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
send_packet: Network is down
dhclient.c:2446: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan0 interface.
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.146 on enxb827ebaceb8a to 255.255.255.255 port 67
receive_packet failed on wlan0: Network is down
DHCPACK of 192.168.0.146 from 192.168.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.0.146 -- renewal in 2861 seconds.
```

## Question

How do I permanently remove the dynamic IP address?

## Clarification

This question is not about assigning a predictable or reserved IP address from the DHCP server (the router in my case). I want to set a static IP address outside the range for DHCP IP address assignments, `192.168.0.100` to `192.168.0.250` set in the router.

All my Ethernet connected devices have manually allocated static IP addresses in the range `192.168.0.2` to `192.168.0.99`. This Pi has the static IP address `192.168.0.65`. I don't want to change that. Neither do I want to change the router setting to include this IP address in the DHCP assignment range.

Thanks

Comment: dynamic IP address is obtained by the dhclient ... so, do not run dhclient

Comment: The post you linked says "First off - we really do not recommend doing this, and we don't support it!" Neither do we.

Comment: @Seamus I have a fresh install of Bullseye, but as usual I did this on another Pi. I agree it is not ready, there are numerous bugs and I am sticking to Buster for daily use.

Comment: You mentioned using `dhclient` to remove your fixed IP address. I've not tried `bullseye` yet, but `dhcpcd` has been the default for a while now... IIRC, `dhclient` is installed, but not used in the default `buster` networking mix.

Comment: @user68186: Yeah - I re-read your Q before that finally sank in on me! But two things: **THING 1:** `dhcpcd` writes other files in `/etc` in the course of doing what it does. `dhclient` **does not** ***un-write*** the files `dhcpcd` makes.  **THING 2 :** `man dhcpcd` states: [`For IPv4, you should use the inform ipaddress option instead of setting a static address.`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/132207/83790).

Comment: @user68186: All that said, your "`connman` answer" may be the correct one, but your solution would be more helpful to others if you'll use `inform` in `dhcpcd.conf` iaw man pg, and see if that resolves the issue by itself. If you do this, you might also consider editing your question to remove the `dhclient` reference as it seems to be a red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update: a better solution: uninstall `connman`

Based on the Q&A and comments in [connman unable to connect to wifi: No carrier](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/133374/83790) it looks like the installation of `connman` was an unintended consequence of upgrading the Pi OS from Buster to Bullseye. Thus, uninstalling `connman` seem to be the best solution.

Note: Uninstalling `connman` will result in the immediate loss of network connection to the Pi. **Do not do this remotely.** Login to the Pi locally and use the command:

```
sudo apt purge connman
```

Followed by the reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Alternately you may use the Add-Remove Software app to remove `connman` and reboot the Pi using the GUI method.

## Original Answer:

### Changing the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` is not enough

At least that's what it looks to me for the Desktop version. I got the idea for where to look from [this guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/11/how-to-upgrade-raspberry-pi-os-10.html).

### Change the *Connman Settings*  via the GUI

Go to Menu -> Preferences -> Connman Settings -> Wired

Click on the Gear icon

[image]

Go to the IPv4 tab on the left panel.

Change the Method from Automatic to Manual, and add the static IP address. Click Apply.

[image]

Finally Reboot the Pi.

After the reboot, the change seems to stick.

### Command line equivalent text based solution

This solution is based on the changes made in the previous section.

Create a file called `settings` at the `/var/lib/connman/ethernet_b827ebaceb8a_cable` where the folder name `ethernet_b827ebaceb8a_cable` is based on the MAC address of the Ethernet port.

The content of the file is:

```
[ethernet_b827ebaceb8a_cable]
Name=Wired
AutoConnect=true
Modified=2021-11-18T14:13:46.329497Z
IPv4.method=manual
IPv6.method=off
IPv6.privacy=disabled
IPv4.netmask_prefixlen=24
IPv4.local_address=192.168.0.65
IPv4.gateway=192.168.0.1
Proxy.Method=direct
Nameservers=192.168.0.1;
IPv4.DHCP.LastAddress=192.168.0.146
```

It looks like these folder and file were created by the changes described in the previous section.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am intrigued how you got this. I did a fresh installation of Raspberry Pi OS-Bullseye (default - Desktop), which continues to use `dhcpcd` (although I had expected `systemd-networkd`). I have seen no other reports of Connman (except the link you included). `Connman` has been in the repository for years, but I have seen few references to its use.

Comment: @Milliways I got it mainly by trial and errors. The linked article gave me the idea of where to look in the GUI. When I found the "Method" selector was set to "Automatic" when I had already changed the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, I knew I had to try changing it in the GUI. I still don't know how to make the same change in `connmand` via the terminal.

Comment: [Some doubts are now being expressed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/133374/83790) about how `connman` came to be installed in `bullseye`. I've trawled through other sources & Rpi docs but have yet to find anything indicating that `connman` has displaced `dhcpcd`. AFAIK, `connman` & `dhcpcd` are **incompatible**. By that I mean they are likely to interfere with each other - perhaps in ways that are difficult to predict. If you're not interested in maintaining this answer (and that's fine as. many don't) feel free to disregard this comment. I mostly just wanted to give a 'heads-up'.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for the heads up. The Q&A you linked makes sense. I will uninstall connman today and if all goes well, update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Seamus I have updated my answer.

Comment: I think that's a better answer - I'd vote for it again if I could. :)

Comment: As I understand it now (which is to say, not very well) this situation w/ `connman` only happens when one upgrades `buster-to-bullseye`; i.e. a fresh install doesn't suffer this issue. If this is correct, I wonder what one uses in lieu of `connman` to make network changes from the desktop?

Comment: Thanks! I found the answer to your question about network changes in GUI, while trying various things related to this questions. If you want, For example, now I can answer how to set static IP address via the GUI. :)

Comment: @Seamus I have answered your question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133424/how-to-set-up-static-ip-address-via-the-desktop-gui-in-buster-bullseye/133426#133426)

Comment: It took me ages to work out why my static settings weren't working.  Turns out that connman was doing something I didn't ask it to: setting my ip with dhcp.  The other answer that says that it is bad practice to use static and dhcp addresses on the same subnet is simply wrong.  I really don't like it when people make up stuff like that for no reason.

Comment: @pdr having both static and dynamic IP addresses in the same subnet is fine. My router defines a range (subset of the subnet) for dynamic IP address assignment, and leaves the rest for static IP address. For example `192.168.0.100-200` is reserved for dynamic IP address. The rest you can assign as static. It may be a bad idea to pick a static IP address in the range reserved for dynamic addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded a Buster install to Bullseye (for pre-release testing of my software) and noted something similar.

There appear to be differences in the `dpkg` rules, but as it wasn't important to my testing I just installed a workaround.

No problems with a fresh installation of Bullseye.

NOTE using static addresses on a network with a DHCP server is a poor practice and leads to the problem you describe. If you want **known** addresses use `request` - See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Thanks! The linked answer is very useful. I could setup my router to reserve a specific IP address within the DHCP range using the Pi's Ethernet MAC address. But that's not what I want.

Comment: @user68186: I hadn't seen your answer when I made my comment to Milliways, but yes, [the guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/11/how-to-upgrade-raspberry-pi-os-10.html) you linked was where I'd seen the reference to `connman`. So - if I understand all of this correctly, the `connman` **is** part of the default `buster` distribution? I guess `connmand` is the command??

Comment: @Milliways: "Not under your answer"?! Are you serious? I'm happy to follow the rules, but I've not seen one that applies to comments like this.

Comment: @Seamus It is not a rule, but I don't need to be notified of a conversation which has NOTHING to do with the Answer. It is just annoying, and the other poster has his answer. There is a chat for discussions.

Comment: Well that's just it - it does have something to do with the answer. I replied to a comment. IMHO, placing that reply somewhere else is confusing. I try not to practice confusion when I can avoid it. I'm sorry if that upsets you.