# How to set up static IP address via the desktop GUI in Buster/Bullseye?

Tags: static-ip, gui, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

## Background

I know how to set up a static IP address by editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os/37921#37921) lists many ways.

For example, I have added the following lines:

```
# Custom static IP address for eth0
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.65/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
```

The interface name may be different in your Pi.

This method works fine for me in both Buster and Bullseye.

This method directly assigns a static IP address to the Pi. This is different from requesting a specific IP address from the dynamic IP address range set in the router or assigning a specific IP address to the Pi in the router settings.

## Question

How do I achieve the same objective of assigning a static IP address via the GUI without manually editing the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is the GUI way to set a static IP address in the Raspberry Pi OS

If your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` has the following lines:

```
interface enxb827ebaceb8a
static ip_address=192.168.0.65/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

You can replicate the same by the following:

Right click on the network icon on the top right corner.

[image]

The icon may look different if you are using WiFi instead of the Ethernet cable pictured here.

Select the **Wireless and Wired Network Settings**

[image]

Change the Interfaces to the one you want to change. Here I have selected the wired network interface.

[image]

set up the IPv4 IP address to the desired one, and the correct IP address for the router, and the router's IP address for the DNS server.

Click close.

### Updated Method `inform` equivalent:

If your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` has the following lines:

```
interface enxb827ebaceb8a
inform 192.168.0.65
```

The equivalent in the GUI should be:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: @Seamus I have updated the answer to include the GUI equivalent of the `inform` option in `dhcpcd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

"In Bullseye it is a longer string of numbers and letters"
This is a *Predictable Network Interface Name* which is normal for most Linux distributions.

If you did a fresh installation Bullseye would use `eth0` - you presumably did one of the unsupported "upgrades" which fail to install/update dpkg rules.

You CAN get normal Pi names if you pass `net.ifnames=0` on the kernel command line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697).

Incidentally there is no need to obscure the value, it is just derived from MAC.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have updated my question based on your input. I knew that the "bunch of numbers and letters" is called *Predictable Network Interface Name* and is derived from the MAC. I was not sure that the switch of the interface name was another consequence of the unsupported upgrade process. Thanks again.