# Failing adding Access Point to RPiZero2W Bullseye following Ingo's guide

Tags: wifi, access-point, systemd-networkd, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

A little more than a year ago, I followed @Ingo's guides [1] and [2] to switch my RPi Zero W Buster to systemd-networkd and then add an AP in the repeater mode (not bridge).

Now, I'm trying to do the same on a brand new RPi Zero 2W running on Bullseye (lite, 32-bit).
1st part to use systemd-networkd is ok and working fine.
Following the 2nd guide (like I did months ago on Buster) creates no error but at the end:

- the access point is there
- client can connect to it
- but the AP interface doesn't get an IPv4 address, doesn't serve DHCP to the clients and IPv6 is back

## Starting point : working systemd-networkd on wlan0

*File: /etc/wap_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf*

```
country=fr
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GRUOP=netdev
p2p_disabled=1
network={
  scan_ssid=1
  ssid="MYWLANSSID"
  psk="MYWLANPASSWORD"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

*File: /etc/systemd/network/08-wifi.network*

```
[Match]
Name=wl*

[Network]
LLMNR=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
MulticastDNS=no
DNS=1.1.1.1 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
# Option: using DHCP
DHCP=ipv4
# Option: using static address
#Address=192.168.168.240/24
#Gateway=192.168.168.254

[DHCP]
UseDNS=no
```

*Result for: ip addr*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:76:65:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.168.240/24 brd 192.168.168.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 42979sec preferred_lft 42979sec
```

I also added the `DNSSEC=no` line to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` to workaround the "DNSSEC verification failed" problem that I encountered last year with my PiZero/Buster.

At this stage, everything works fine. IP addresses are only V4 as expected due to `LinkLocalAddressing=no`

## 2nd step, adding hostapd, accesspoint@.service as per guide [2]

*File: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf*

```
driver=nl80211
ssid=MYAPSSID
country_code=FR
hw_mode=g
channel=1
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=MYAPPASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

*File: accesspoint@.service: exactly as per the guide*

*Override on wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service: exactly as per the guide*

*File: /etc/systemd/network/12-ap.network*

```
[Match]
Name=ap@*

[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=no
IPMasquerade=yes
Address=192.168.107.1/24
DHCPServer=yes

[DHCPServer]
DNS=192.168.107.1
```

## After reboot

*Result from `ip addr`*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:76:65:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2a01:e0a:27e:6f60:e65f:1ff:fe76:65e9/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 86362sec preferred_lft 86362sec
    inet6 fe80::e65f:1ff:fe76:65e9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ap@wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:76:65:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::e65f:1ff:fe76:65e9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- Wifi client interface wlan0 has lost IPv4 and get 2 IPv6 address.
- AP interface ap@wlan0 doesn't get its static IPv4 address and get an IPv6 instead
- AP is present and device can connect but doesn't get a DHCP IPv4 address

*systemctl status accesspoint@wlan0.service (result cut on the right due to serial terminal)*

```
● accesspoint@wlan0.service - accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/accesspoint@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-02-13 17:48:30 CET; 4min 55s ago
    Process: 319 ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap@wlan0 type __ap (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 357 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 523)
        CPU: 144ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-accesspoint.slice/accesspoint@wlan0.service
             └─357 /usr/sbin/hostapd -i ap@wlan0 /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Feb 13 17:48:29 piz2 systemd[1]: Starting accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version)...
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 systemd[1]: Started accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version).
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 hostapd[357]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 hostapd[357]: ap@wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 hostapd[357]: Using interface ap@wlan0 with hwaddr e4:5f:01:76:65:e9 and ssid "MYAPSSID"
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 hostapd[357]: ap@wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 hostapd[357]: ap@wlan0: AP-ENABLED
```

*systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service*

```
● wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-02-13 17:48:30 CET; 8min ago
   Main PID: 359 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 523)
        CPU: 157ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-wpa_supplicant.slice/wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
             └─359 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0

Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Feb 13 17:48:30 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=FR
Feb 13 17:48:31 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'MYWLANSSID'
Feb 13 17:48:32 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: Associated with 88:c3:97:f2:25:ec
Feb 13 17:48:32 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Feb 13 17:48:32 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 88:c3:97:f2:25:ec [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Feb 13 17:48:32 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 88:c3:97:f2:25:ec completed [id=0 id_str=]
Feb 13 17:48:32 piz2 wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=CN
```

*systemctl status hostapd.service*

```
● hostapd.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit hostapd.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

As of now, my conclusion is that systemd-networkd doesn't seem to read correctly the `08-wifi.network`and `12-ap.network` files
But I have no idea why.
The same is running find on a RPiZeroW with Buster

TIA for your advices and suggestions

---

[1] [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking/108593#108593)

[2] [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge/89804#89804)