# Raspberry Pi WiFi Ethernet Bridge with Proxy ARP Not Broadcasting Host Name (Brother Printer Issue)

Tags: wifi, ethernet, pi-zero-w-2

First, I need to say thank you to the users who provided the guides to get the basic setup of the WiFi-Ethernet bridge:

1. [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking/108593?newreg=703c43189ca44decabb7041e2b4db3da)
2. [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking/108593?newreg=703c43189ca44decabb7041e2b4db3da)

Without you, I wouldn't even be here to ask this question. That being said, I do have a functional Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W that connects to my home network via WiFi and has a micro-USB ethernet dongle to connect to my old - yet reliable - Brother MFC-7440N printer/scanner/copier fax (which lacks WiFi but has ethernet LAN functionality).

I previously had the printer/scanner drivers looking up the printer by Host Name and my hope was to continue to use that setup. However, SystemD-NetworkD/Proxy ARP setup apparently isn't broadcasting the host name of the printer. I previously was using a cheap commercial IOGear WiFi-Ethernet bridge (which constantly dropped from the network and was unreliable - hence why I'm replacing it with the RPi) but it did broadcast the printer's host name.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to enable such functionality with this setup? Currently I'm just using a static IP assignment as the Brother drivers only allow host name or static IP. However, I'd like to use host name, if possible, as I have the RPI Z2W setup to be able to assign a range of DHCP IPs via ethernet and I'm thinking using DHCP instead of a static IP within the DHCP range will prevent headaches in the long run if/when additional devices may get added via a switch off the ethernet dongle.